# adding an external property to include index for vertix in graph (boost)

Tags: c++, boost, graph, indexing, boost-graph

I'm trying to use an associative_property_map to include index for vertices, but I get the following error with the following simple code, what is the problem ?

```
#include <boost/graph/iteration_macros.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

struct NodeData
{
    int label;
};

struct EdgeData
{
    int age;
};

typedef map<vecS, size_t> IndexMap;
IndexMap mapIndex;
associative_property_map<IndexMap> propmapIndex(mapIndex);

typedef adjacency_list<setS, setS, undirectedS, NodeData, EdgeData> Graph;
typedef Graph::vertex_descriptor NodeID;
typedef Graph::edge_descriptor EdgeID;

int main()
{
    Graph g;

    NodeID n0 = add_vertex(g); g[n0].label = -1;
    NodeID n1 = add_vertex(g); g[n1].label = -1;

    EdgeID edge; bool ok;
    tie(edge, ok) = boost::add_edge(n0, n1, g);
    if (ok) g[edge].age = 10;

    int i=0;
    BGL_FORALL_VERTICES(v, g, Graph)
    {
        put(propmapIndex, v, i++);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Errors:

> ```
> c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1........\include\boost\property_map\property_map.hpp||In
> ```
>
> function 'void boost::put(const boost::put_get_helper&, K, const V&)
>   [with PropertyMap = boost::associative_property_map, std::allocator >
>
> > > , Reference = unsigned int&, K = void*, V = int]':| C:\Users\memo\Desktop\Debuged\boostGraph\main.cpp|39|instantiated from
> > >       here| c:\program
> > >       files\codeblocks\mingw\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1........\include\boost\property_map\property_map.hpp|361|error:
> > >       no match for 'operator[]' in '(const boost::associative_property_map,
> > >       std::allocator > > >&)((const boost::associative_property_map,
> > >       std::allocator > > >*)(& pa))[k]'| c:\program
> > >       files\codeblocks\mingw\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1........\include\boost\property_map\property_map.hpp|498|note:
> > >       candidates are: typename
> > >       UniquePairAssociativeContainer::value_type::second_type&
> > >       boost::associative_property_map::operator[](const typename
> > >       UniquePairAssociativeContainer::key_type&) const [with
> > >       UniquePairAssociativeContainer = std::map, std::allocator > >]| ||===
> > >       Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vertex descriptor must be specified to IndexMap, so it's `map<NodeID, size_t>` and not `map<vecS, size_t>` :

```
<...>
typedef Graph::vertex_descriptor NodeID;

typedef map<NodeID, size_t> IndexMap;
IndexMap mapIndex;
associative_property_map<IndexMap> propmapIndex(mapIndex);
<...>

// indexing all vertices
int i=0;
BGL_FORALL_VERTICES(v, g, Graph)
{
   put(propmapIndex, v, i++);
}
```