# Saving no-parallel edge graph to a graphml file using boost

Tags: c++, boost-graph

Following code save a graph into a graphml file. It works!. But when I replace `typedef adjacency_list< vecS, vecS, directedS,` with `typedef adjacency_list< setS, setS, directedS,` so that no duplicate vertex or edge is inserted into the graph, it complains.

```
#include <boost/graph/graphml.hpp>

using namespace std;
typedef struct {
  string name;
  string label;
} vertex_type_t;

int main(int,char*[])
{

  using namespace boost;

  typedef adjacency_list< vecS, vecS, directedS, 
      vertex_type_t > graph_t;

  graph_t g;
  graph_t::vertex_descriptor v1 = add_vertex(g);
  graph_t::vertex_descriptor v2 = add_vertex(g);

  dynamic_properties dp;
  dp.property("name", get(&vertex_type_t::name, g));

  write_graphml(std::cout, g, dp, true);

  return 0;
}
```

I can not make much out of the error. I believe following is the main error.

```
/usr/include/boost/graph/graphml.hpp: In function ‘void boost::write_graphml(std::ostream&, const Graph&, VertexIndexMap, const boost::dynamic_properties&, bool) [with Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::setS, boost::directedS, vertex_type_t>, VertexIndexMap = boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::setS, boost::directedS, vertex_type_t>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t>, std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]’:
/usr/include/boost/graph/graphml.hpp:345:5:   instantiated from ‘void boost::write_graphml(std::ostream&, const Graph&, const boost::dynamic_properties&, bool) [with Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::setS, boost::directedS, vertex_type_t>, std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
write_graphviz.cpp:24:39:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/graph/graphml.hpp:301:9: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::operator<< [with _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]((* & out), ((const char*)"    <node id=\"n")) << boost::get [with PropertyMap = boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::setS, boost::directedS, vertex_type_t>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t>, Reference = const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, K = void*]((*(const boost::put_get_helper<const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::setS, boost::directedS, vertex_type_t>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >*)(& vertex_index)), (* & v.std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator* [with _Tp = void*, std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::reference = void* const&]()))’
/usr/include/boost/graph/graphml.hpp:301:9: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:110:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:110:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const boost::detail::error_property_not_found’ to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type&) {aka std::basic_ostream<char>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>&)}’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:119:7: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type = std::basic_ios<char>]
```

I really want to use setS as edge containers. I am not sure how to modify this program such that it starts working since error message is not making much sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that [`write_graphml`](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/write_graphml.html) requires a VertexIndexMap in your graph and only `adjacency_list`s with `VertexList=vecS` have one created by default. You have to create one yourself if you use `listS` or `setS`.

> I really want to use setS as edge containers.

If you only need to use `setS` in your `OutEdgeList` you can simply use:

```
typedef adjacency_list< setS, vecS, directedS, 
  vertex_type_t > graph_t;
```

If you must use `setS` for both then your program should be (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8555863/1252091)):

```
#include <boost/graph/graphml.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/iteration_macros.hpp>

#include <map>

using namespace std;
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    string label;
} vertex_type_t;

int main ( int, char*[] )
{

    using namespace boost;

    typedef adjacency_list < setS, vecS, directedS,
            vertex_type_t > graph_t;

    typedef graph_t::vertex_descriptor NodeID; //define your Vertex Index Map
    typedef std::map<NodeID, size_t> IndexMap;
    IndexMap mapIndex;
    boost::associative_property_map<IndexMap> propmapIndex ( mapIndex );

    graph_t g;
    graph_t::vertex_descriptor v1 = add_vertex ( g );
    graph_t::vertex_descriptor v2 = add_vertex ( g );

    int i = 0;                                  //fill your Vertex Index Map
    BGL_FORALL_VERTICES ( v, g, graph_t )
    {
        put ( propmapIndex, v, i++ );
    }

    g[v1].name="FirstVertex";
    g[v2].name="SecondVertex";

    dynamic_properties dp;
    dp.property ( "name", get ( &vertex_type_t::name, g ) );

    write_graphml ( std::cout, g, propmapIndex, dp, true );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is this that the new graphtype (with setS) does not satisfy the requirements to the write_graphml(..) function: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/graph/doc/write_graphml.html

It states that "The graph's type must be a model of VertexListGraph." which it described here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/graph/doc/VertexListGraph.html